# intel video driver not enabled by default?

Tags: intel

I have an i5 laptop with integrated Intel HD graphics. Recently I had some bad performance of 3D graphics applications and upon looking at Xorg.0.log file I could see no indication of the intel video driver being loaded. I checked and the xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04 was installed. I then tried adding a file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf which loaded the driver and now I could see in the Xorg log files that the intel driver was loaded. I also realized that my user was not in the video group, which has access to /dev/dri device, so I also fixed that.

I was wondering if this is expected for Elementary OS, which I would have thought to already configure this by default to improve user experience. Is this a bug that should be reported?